# Find if there exists a sum of n elements, of a Seq, equal to a value

Tags: scala

Example:
Having an array

```
arr[10,-5,-115,6,70,25,345,-35]
```

find if the sum of any 4 of its elements is 100.

Comment: Could you please improve your question giving an example or showing what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

use  **combinations** `https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.4/scala/collection/Seq.html#combinations(n:Int):Iterator[Repr]`

```
scala> Seq(10,-5,-115,6,70,25,345,-35).combinations(4).map(_.sum).exists(_ == 100)
res15: Boolean = true

scala> Seq(10,-5,-115,6,50,25,345,-35).combinations(4).map(_.sum).exists(_ == 100)
res16: Boolean = false

scala> Seq(10,-5,-115,6,80,25,345,-35).combinations(4).map(_.sum).exists(_ == 100)
res17: Boolean = false
```